# Quartiles query in sql

Tags: mysql

I have code like this:

```
SELECT `pelamarmagisterrangkuman`.`major` AS `ProgramStudi`,
count(IPKS1) as N,
AVG(IPKS1) as Mean,
MIN(IPKS1) as Minimum,
MAX(IPKS1) as Maximum,
StdDev(IPKS1) as StDev,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT(IPKS1 ORDER BY IPKS1 SEPARATOR ','),
',', 50/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS decimal) AS `Median`,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT(IPKS1 ORDER BY IPKS1 SEPARATOR ','),
',', 25/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS decimal) AS `Q1`,
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT(IPKS1 ORDER BY IPKS1 SEPARATOR ','),
',', 75/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS decimal) AS `Q3`
FROM `pelamarmagisterrangkuman` where `pelamarmagisterrangkuman`.`IPKS1` != 0 and `pelamarmagisterrangkuman`.`TahunDaftar` = 2012 group by `pelamarmagisterrangkuman`.`major`
```

COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX, and MIN can work properly. But, quartiles cannot work properly. I mean, the result of the code above is integer values. But, the result that I expected is not just integer value, but also float value because my data is in float and integer value. What may I do to fix that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Avoid integers in the arithmetic e.g.

50.0/100.0 *  cast(COUNT(*) as decimal) + 1.0

Comment: I thought the problem was solved?  If all parts of the arithmetic are decimals then the result is decimal, but you may need to format the output to display them. Without sample data hard to do much more. Also "It's not working" could mean many things, please be specific.